# Why does adding a font:menu to my CSS cause pages to render very differently?

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser

I can't seem to find much information on the "menu" font.

I'm trying to implement suckerfish-style CSS menus based on [this turorial](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/create-a-multilevel-dropdown-menu-with-css-and-improve-it-via-jquery), while trying to maintain an existing look & feel for an intranet-based application.

As soon as I add:

```
font:menu;
```

to the `#nav a` style, the line-height set in `#nav` is ignored in both FF and Chrome, but not in IE 8.

What is the "menu" font?  What alternatives do I have that won't break the menus?

Comment: where did you get `font: menu;` from to begin with? I see no reference to it in the tutorial.

Comment: No, it's part of the current intranet application - it uses the font:menu for navigation elements.  I need to maintain the look & feel as much as possible, but would like it to also work in FF and Chrome even though IE is the current standard.

Comment: have you tried a graceful fallback `font: 14px sans-serif; font: menu;`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the `line-height` issue (I recommend to prepare a small test case and post it here), but the `menu` font is described in the [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#propdef-font):

> The following values refer to system fonts:
>
> **caption**
>       The font used for captioned controls (e.g., buttons, drop-downs,
>   etc.).
>   **icon**
>       The font used to label icons.
>   **menu**
>       The font used in menus (e.g., dropdown menus and menu lists).
>   **message-box**
>       The font used in dialog boxes.
>   **small-caption**
>       The font used for labeling small controls.
>   **status-bar**
>       The font used in window status bars.

But, as usual, browsers tend to offer pretty variable compliance degrees with specifications.

---

**Edit:** just read the link. These fonts reset other properties as well. Have you tried `line-height: 1 !important;` :-?

Comment: OK, so these are build-ins that reset all the font properties - but is there any way to know what the defaults are for each different browser?

Comment: @christ - Probably not. It's hard to know even what the default paragraph margin is... I guess CSS resets have become popular for a good reason.